# HTML CSS : unable to position div element

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project where I have a picture on top of my website and with a small space under the picture I want to add a text between 2 horizontal lines . I have made the text and the 2 lines but I have trouble positioning it under my image . I have put the text and the 2 lines inside a div element and I try to position it . 
My code :

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body{
   font-family:Aleo;
    }
.background-container{
 
position:fixed;
 top :0px;
 left:0px;
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 
 
 
} 


.background-container > img {


width:100%;
height:350px;  
display:block;
} 
 
.inside-pic{

position:absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 16px;
color:white;
font-size:45px;
} 
 
.inside-pic>span{
color:orange;

}




#between{
 
 position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
 
 
}

#between:before, #between:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: grey;
}


#between:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>



   
  <div class = "background-container"> 
    
    <img src = "IMAGES/selfhelp.jpg"> 
    <div class = "inside-pic"  >Book<span >House</span> </div> 
  
  </div> 

  <br/>

  <div id = "title"> <h1 id = "between"> List of self-help books </h1> </div>

 <br/><br/>
 
 
 

</body>
```

How the webpage is actually displayed :

[image: my page]

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to position the title with the lines under the image . Thank you in advance

Comment: what you actually want

Comment: I wrote above. To position the "list of self help books " with the 2 horizontal lines below the image

Comment: ok wait, i'm debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/g62nx8ya/

remove this

```
.background-container{
   position:fixed;
   top :0px;
   left:0px;
   height:auto;
   width:100%;
   margin:0;
 }
```

and add `margin:0` to the body

```
body{
  font-family:Aleo;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

body{
   font-family:Aleo;
    }
.background-container{
 
/*position:fixed;*/
 top :0px;
 left:0px;
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 
 
 
} 


.background-container > img {


width:100%;
height:350px;  
display:block;
} 
 
.inside-pic{

position:absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 16px;
color:white;
font-size:45px;
} 
 
.inside-pic>span{
color:orange;

}




#between{
 
 position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
 
 
}

#between:before, #between:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: grey;
}


#between:before {
    margin-left: -50%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>



   
  <div class = "background-container"> 
    
    <img src = "IMAGES/selfhelp.jpg"> 
    <div class = "inside-pic"  >Book<span >House</span> </div> 
  
  </div> 

  <br/>

  <div id = "title"> <h1 id = "between"> List of self-help books </h1> </div>

 <br/><br/>
 
 
 

</body>
```